# scalaz.Equal for path dependent types

Tags: scala, scalaz, path-dependent-type

I'm experimenting with path-dependent types and I run into a problem when trying to write a `scalaz.Equal` instance for it. I have the following structure:

```
class A {
  class B 
}

val a1 = new A 
val b1 = new a1.B   // type a1.B

val a2 = new A 
val b2 = new a2.B   //type a2.B
```

I first wanted to make `b1` "unequalable" (is that a word?) to `b2` at compile time, which I achieved with the following:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

implicit def BEqual[X <: A#B]: scalaz.Equal[X] = Equal.equalA

b1 === b1 //true
b1 === b2 // doesn't compile, good
b2 === b1 // doesn't compile, good
```

My second experiment was try to make equality less restrictive, allowing instances of `A#B` to be compared to each other but not to other types, with:

```
 implicit val  BEqual: scalaz.Equal[A#B] = Equal.equalA
```

But it doesn't work as expected:

```
b1 === b2 //doesnt' compile, === is not a member of a1.B
```

This works however:

```
BEqual.equal(b1,b2)  //compiles
BEqual.equal(b1,"string")   //doesnt' compile, good
```

So, I would like to know why the `===` doesn't work and if I can write an instance of `Equal` that would apply to all `A#B`s?

I tried a home brew solution with implicit conversion and it worked.

```
implicit class abEqual(ab: A#B) {
  def eqab(ab2: A#B) = ab == ab2
}

b1.eqab(b2)  //ok 
b2.eqab(b1)  //ok 
b1.eqab("String")  //doesn't compile, good
```

So why doesn't this work with `scalaz.Equal`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first `BEqual` you're saying that for any subtype of `A#B` you want to provide an `Equal` instance *for that subtype*. When the compiler sees `b1 ===` it therefore finds the `Equal[a.B]` instance, since the static type of `b1` is `a.B`. This makes things work out as you'd expect.

In your second `BEqual`, you're defining an `Equal` instance only for `A#B`. This means that even `b1 === b1` won't compile, since the static type of `b1` is more specific than `A#B`, and `Equal` is invariant in its type parameter. If you upcast your values the instance will work just fine:

```
scala> val ab1: A#B = b1
ab1: A#B = A$B@464ef4fa

scala> val ab2: A#B = b2
ab2: A#B = A$B@2d3b749e

scala> ab1 === ab2
res1: Boolean = false
```

In the version where you call `BEqual.equal` directly, you're essentially accomplishing the same thing—method arguments are always covariant, so when you pass something statically typed as a `a.B` as a `A#B` argument, everything will work just fine. In your hand-rolled implicit class, you're similarly just saying that you want to work with any old `A#B`.

You can see the same kind of thing when you write `Some(1) === Some(1)` vs. `Option(1) === Option(1)` (or `some(1) === some(1)`). Scalaz provides an `Equal` for `Option[A: Equal]`, but not for `Some[A: Equal]`, and when the first argument has a more specific static type the `Option` instance won't be found.

This isn't something you want to work around, since the invariance of Scalaz's `Equal` is intentional. If you want to work with `A#B` values as `A#B` values in this context, you'll need to upcast them explicitly.

Comment: "and `Equal` is invariant in its type parameter" . Right there, that was the detail I overlooked! I agree I dont' want to work it around, it's the correct behavior! Thanks!